# CakePhp 3 Not unique table/alias: TableName

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've bin searching for days now without fixing this problem:

I am getting this error message:
`Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'Posts'`

And this is my initialize method in the PostTable class:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('posts');
    $this->displayField('post_id');
    $this->primaryKey('post_id');
    $this->addBehavior('timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Posts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'className' => 'Users',
        'foreignKey' => 'fk_post_user_id', //<- foreignkey name are correct
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

    $this->belongsTo('Pictures',[
        'foreignKey' => 'fk_post_picture_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}
```

And this is my database:

[image: Database ERD]

i know the error has to do something with the foreignkeys of the `posts` table, but i don't know what is wrong with the `belongTo` in my initialize method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have self association you need to use a different alias for that association. So instead of

```
$this->belongsTo('Posts', [
    'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

use

```
$this->belongsTo('ParentPosts', [
    'className' => 'Posts',
    'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

Comment: I need a self association, because otherwise i get this error message: `Posts is not associated with Posts`

Comment: Fix your find() call. Use `ParentPosts` instead of `Posts` when containing the association.

Comment: btw, @YvesHendseth a self-referencing association on/via the primary-key, that doesn't make much sense to me? o_O

Comment: @ndm i know, i don't undestand it either. Because in my application a post shouldn't have a parent post...

Comment: @YvesHendseth Then why did you create that association? If it was baked, then this is because you are not following the naming conventions, where columns should not be prefixed with the table name, unless they should act as a foreign key.

Comment: Yes, this is clear from the database diagram. To match Cake naming conventions, the index field on all tables should just be id, not post_id for posts, user_id for users, etc. In fact, having the table name prefixed onto every single column seems like you're going add a ton of extra work for yourself, like you'll have to provide a label parameter for every input, because Cake will by default label the "user_username" field as "User Username", for example.